# How to create a good hypermedia format using JMSSerializerBundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, hateoas, jmsserializerbundle, hypermedia

Lets say I want to create an XML-response that will looks something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf‐8"?>
<product xmlns="urn:com.acme.prods" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/xlink">
  <id>1234</id>
  <name>Red Stapler</name>
  <price currency="EUR">3.14</price>
  <atom:link rel="payment" type="application/com.acme.shop+xml"
             href="http://acme.com/products/1234/payment" />
</product>
```

Given an domain model that looks something like the following:

```
<?php
// Product.php
namespace Acme\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity;
use Acme\Bundle\ProductBundle\Money\Money;

class Product
{
  /**
   * @var integer
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $name;

  /**
   * @var Money
   */
  private $price;

  [..]
}
```

And a money-class along the lines of:

```
<?php
// Money.php
namespace Acme\Bundle\ProductBundle\Money;

class Money
{
  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $currency;
  /**
   *
   */
  private $amount;
}
```

Now, to my questions. It would be pretty simple to create a response that looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf‐8"?>
<product>
  <id>1234</id>
  <name>Red Stapler</name>
  <price currency="EUR">3.14</price>
</product>
```

using either annotations, XML or YAML to tell JMSSerializerBundle how to serialize the Product-object. However, the `xmlns:atom` and `<atom:link>` entries should not be specified by the entity, since it should have no concept of **how** and **where** it is located. You could also imagine more links with different `rel`-attributes, such as `edit`.
One solution that comes to mind would be a service that listens to serialization events for specific objects, and adds these attributes and tags as appropriate. The service could use DI to get hold of the `Request`, `Router`-service etc to generate these links in a format that is suitable for the requested format. I.E in an XML-response, it could set the appropriate type to `application/media-format+xml`, whereas in a json-response, it could generate something like

```
"links": [
   {
     "rel": "payment", 
     "type": "application/media-format+json", 
     "href": "[...]"
   }
]
```

Now, in [the documentation for JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle), I find annotations for `@PreSerialize`, and `@PostSerialize`, but they seem to only be able to call methods on the object being serialized.
Does anyone know how/if this can be achieved? Or do I have to use a templating engine such as Twig and manually create the XML-response?

Comment: Very interesting question. After poking a bit around, I thing there is no other solution then polluting your entity with additional attributes used only for the serialization... What appears to be missing in the bundle is a possibility to handle the complete serialization of a particular object with another class.

Comment: [You can Check Here 1: specify-group-per-attribute ][1]


[Also here 2: jms serializer bundle-complex-generated-value][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665369/jmsserializerbundle-specify-group-per-attribute
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475171/jmsserializerbundle-complex-generated-value

Answer (score 3):

The Serializer Bundle alone might not be enough for this situation as it is only concerned with serialization and deserialization, not more complex semantical tasks.

I would suggest looking into [FSCHateoasBundle](https://github.com/TheFootballSocialClub/FSCHateoasBundle) to implement a pretty hypermedia format for your API.