# JMSSerializerBundle complex generated value

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I need implement RESTful API for my site on symfony 2, so i use FOSRestBundle + JMSSerializerBundle

I have such serializer yml for my entity:

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Product:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    accessor_order: custom
    custom_accessor_order: [id, title]
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true

        title:
            expose: true

    virtual_properties:
        getMainPhoto:
            serialized_name: photo
```

The problem is that `getMainPhoto` return me url to **full sized** image. I want preprocess this url before sending response to api client where i can generate new url to resized version of such image. I already have service in sf2 which can do this job:

```
$resized_url = $someService->generateResizedUrl($item->getMainPhoto(), 640, 480);
```

But i don't know how can i use this service with JMSSerializer. Maybe there is some callbacks for FOSRestBundle\JMSSerializerBundle just before it send response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the documentation](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer#documentation). There are is a number of events and/or annotations you can use to hook into the serialization process.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the original url, and then add the resized url using http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system#serializer-post-serialize event.

You have to write a listener that listen when "Product" instances are serialized.